# Copying table subset from one database to another with same schema

Tags: postgresql, data-migration, self-reference

I am trying to subset of a table from one table to another

> users(id, name, referrer_id, country_id)

This table have self referential association with referrer_id as foreign key to itself.

I tried following query

```sh
psql source_table -c 'COPY (SELECT * FROM users where country_id = 2) TO stdout' | psql target_table -c 'COPY users FROM stdin'
```

Issue with above approach is refer may not be in the same subset, so it will show the error

> ERROR:  insert or update on table "users" violates foreign key constraint "users_referrer_id_fk"
>
> DETAIL:  Key (referrer_id)=(123) is not present in table "users".

I tried to use ON CONFLICT but it seems that ON CONFLICT syntax is not available in COPY TABLE syntax. Is there a better way to transfer subset of tables between databases

I am looking for some thing like this

```
psql lx_default -c 'COPY (SELECT * FROM users where country_id = 97) TO stdout' | psql lx_hongkong -c 'COPY users FROM stdin ON CONFLICT DO SET users.referrer_id=null'
```

Above SQL is syntactically invalid

Comment: cross posted at https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/238038/copying-table-subset-from-one-database-to-another-with-same-schema

Comment: You shoudlnt cross post your questions

Comment: Well disable the foreign key constraint or dont bring rows without their referal)id on the other table.

Comment: I am looking for some think like this `psql lx_default -c 'COPY (SELECT * FROM users where country_id = 97) TO stdout' | psql lx_hongkong -c 'COPY users FROM stdin ON CONFLICT DO SET users.referrer_id=null'`

Comment: I doubt you can do that. My suggestion bring the whole table and then delete the rows you dont need